# Nvidia Prime suddenly stopped working

Tags: kubuntu, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

I installed clean Kubuntu 16.04 on my new laptop two weeks ago. Asus Zenbook UX501VW, Intel HD Graphiscs 520 Skylake + Geforce 960M. Then installed nvidia prime (nvidia-367) next to bumbelebee (I know that it is not recommended mix them) followed by this article: http://nlug.ml1.co.uk/2016/02/an-almost-authoritative-guide-to-nvidia-prime-and-bumblebee/5065

Everything worked perfect. I could switch between graphic cards using nvidia  prime `sudo prime-select intel / nvidia` or use bumbelebee `optirun` on prime intel profile. Restarted laptop many times, tested benchmarks. Decided that finally got it stable, it is time to configure my work space. Istalled needed stuff. Meantime had to install kernel 4.6 and create file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with content:

```
Section "Extensions"
        Option "XVideo" "Disable"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option      "TearFree" "true"
   Option      "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

... because there were issues playing movies on Intel HD 520. Everything did on intel profile. Today wanted switch to nvidia prime and after logout got black screen of death. So CTRL+ALT+F1, switch back to intel `sudo prime-select intel`, restart and everything is ok. Tried remove bumblebee, nvidia etc and install everything again (this time without bumblebee) but same problem. Notice that even `optirun` stopped working. Can't show exactly error because bumblebee is removed but it was related to "can't find module "mouse"". Does anyone know what could broke this? Kernel 4.6? How to run diagnostic reboot to see what error is behind that black screen? This is my grub entry:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Have you tried `primusrun` instead of `optirun`?

Comment: What is `primusrun`? Is it a part of `bumblebee` or `nvidia-prime`? I removed bumblebee. `optirun` didn't work, `sudo prime-select nvidia` resulted with black screen so even if `primusrun` would work then it is not enough for me, I'm more interested in full session on nvidia instead of running separated apps

Comment: I found it more useful to use nvidia only for specific programs as intel is enough for most and nvidia can be dedicated to a single program when I need. The `primusrun` command belongs into the `primus` package. I have found that it runs sometimes when `optirun` doesn't. Also, it's more practical to debug stuff if you have your environment working. Bumblebee creates another X-server using nvidia and feeds its contents into the render window, allowing you to comfortably view the error messages and troubleshoot them.

Comment: Well, tried install `primus`. It has `bumblebee` package in dependencies and I would not like back to this and configure it again. My goal now is fix `sudo prime-select nvidia`. Black screen is before login screen. How can I see on which place/command it is hanging? CTRL+ALT+F1 work so it is not totally frozen. Seems like error while running X server on nvidia prime profile. After CTRL+ALT+F1 I can login in commandline mode and switch back to intel by `sudo prime-select intel` and then `sudo reboot`

Comment: You don't have to reboot, using `sudo service lightdm stop` and `sudo service lightdm start` is usually enough. As for fixing your issue, you may have some stuff remaining in your system, what may help is `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` to get rid of all nvidia-related packages and everything they had and then install it back clean.

Comment: Tried that too. Didn't help